# Diminuir tamanho do Spinner

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou tentando utilizar o Spinner do jquery, que por padrão tem 8 campos, e é muito grande para o meu objetivo, que no caso seriam 2 campos.
Já dei uma olhada em sua documentação, mas o máximo que consegui foi diminuir sua fonte, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
<input readonly id="spinner" name="value">

<style>
.ui-widget input,
.ui-widget select,
.ui-widget textarea,
.ui-widget button {
    font-size: small;
    maxlength: 3;
    outline: 1px; /* add this bit */
    border: 1px inset;
}
</style>
```

É possível fazer essa customização?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Você pode fazer algo como isso:

```
<input id="spinner" name="value" max="99"></input>
```

Com um `max="99"` você limita 99 como o maior número possível, e assim só vai até dois dígitos. Você pode também usar `min="0"`, caso não queira números negativos.
Depois é só diminuir a largura do input.

### Segue Exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  var spinner = $("#spinner").spinner();

  $("button").button();
});
```

```css
#spinner {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<p>
  <input id="spinner" name="value" min="0" max="99">
</p>
```